# Find a cell in a table or range, if the cell matches it then it returns the value next to the cell in the range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openoffice-calc

Sorry for my confusing English though.
[image]
The data in each row is one contract, as you can see the first record (row3) is May18. Thus today's price E3 should reflect May18 price.

D13:E17 are data that I've been getting from the external website. They are constantly changing once a few months. Every time they change it, I have to fix my formula.

whenever the website changes, my formula in column E changes from

```
=INDEX($E$14:$E$17;MATCH('May18';$E$14:$E$17;0))
```

to

```
=INDEX($E$14:$E$17;MATCH('Jul18';$E$14:$E$17;0))
```

or

```
=INDEX($E$14:$E$17;MATCH('Mar18';$E$14:$E$17;0))
```

to

```
=INDEX($E$14:$E$17;MATCH('May18';$E$14:$E$17;0))
```

If the website changes and I don't double check, then I would have Jul18 value in May18 record. In this case, I would have 0.6849 in E3 instead of 0.6776

I want the today's column to return the data according to the existing column B even though the D14:E17 are constantly changing.

There used to be Oct17 but it's gone now.

The pic before the data got updated:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should work for you.

```
=VLOOKUP($B3,$D$14:$E$17,2)
```

Paste it in E3 and copy down to the required rows.
You might consider using a named range, like $D$14:$E$17 named as "Contracts". Then you could use the above formula modified as below.

```
=VLOOKUP($B3,Contracts,2)
```